# How to create regtype column in postgreSQL that includes length and precision parameter

Tags: postgresql, types, create-table

I would like to store some meta information in postgreSQL database.
This requires to store the column type information. I am aware of regtype type but it does not store information about length or precision.

How can I achieve this. I could use a TEXT column instead but then I would need to take care of all the validations and referential integrity. Is there more convenient way o achieve this?

Below I present example code.

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(name TEXT,
sql_type regtype);

INSERT INTO foo
VALUES('my_field_1', 'character varying'::regtype);

INSERT INTO foo
VALUES('my_field_2', 'VARCHAR(50)'::regtype);

INSERT INTO foo
VALUES('my_field_3', 'NUMERIC(32,16)'::regtype);

SELECT * from foo;
```

The result is as follows:

```
name             sql_type
text             regtype
-------------------------------------
my_field_1      character varying
my_field_2      character varying
my_field_3      numeric
```

Expected result:

```
name             sql_type
text             regtype
-------------------------------------
my_field_1      character varying  <-- I won't need such cases
my_field_2      character varying(50)
my_field_3      numeric(32,16)
```

I am currently using PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: Postgres internally stores a column definition as a regtype along with a typmod, which holds the length/scale/precision (see the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html)). You can turn them back into strings with [`format_type()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE).

Comment: @NickBarnes: Thanks for reply, I see that typemod and format_type() are both internal C implementations and are not available as such in user code. I am looking for a solution in SQL / plpgsql

Comment: You can certainly use typemod values and call `format_type()` in SQL. The only tricky bit is getting hold of a typemod in the first place (easy if you're pulling these types from existing table definitions, not so much if you need to construct them yourself). But it's definitely possible; here's an example: http://rextester.com/JLK17510

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `regclass` is a convenience type that internally is just the type's numeric object identifier, so it does not contain information about scale, precision, length and other *type modifiers*.

*I* would store the type together with its modifiers as `text`.

But if you want, you can also do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE coldef (
   column_name              name     NOT NULL,
   data_type                regtype  NOT NULL,
   numeric_precision        smallint
      CHECK (numeric_precision IS NULL
             OR numeric_precision BETWEEN 1 AND 1000),
   numeric_scale            smallint
      CHECK (numeric_scale IS NULL
             OR numeric_scale BETWEEN 0 AND numeric_precision),
   character_maximum_length integer
      CHECK (character_maximum_length IS NULL
             OR character_maximum_length BETWEEN 1 AND 10485760),
   datetime_precision       smallint
      CHECK (datetime_precision IS NULL
             OR datetime_precision BETWEEN 0 AND 6),
   interval_precision       smallint
      CHECK (interval_precision IS NULL
             OR interval_precision BETWEEN 0 AND 6)
);
```

You can add more check constraints to make sure that there are no forbidden combinations, like a `character varying` with a numeric precision, or that `numeric_precision` must be `NOT NULL` when `numeric_scale` is.

Get inspired by the catalog table `information_schema.columns` that contains the column metadata.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I will stick to TEXT/VARCHAR field containing all the type meta information like "NUMERIC(32,16)". If for some reason I would chose to have separate fields for precision, scale etc, are you aware of a SQL user accessible function that would produce the text output (format_type() equivalent as @NickBarnes suggested in his comment) ?

Comment: No, but it would be simple enough to build such a function with a couple of `CASE` expressions.